# Can't turn on automatic spell check in Libre Office for a new document

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I am running the latest LibreOffice(5.2.1.2) on a Windows box. I've created a new document and have spelling mistakes in it, but spell check isn't working. When I open my older documents, spell check works and shows me the typos in them.
When I press F7 in the document I created, here is what I see:

[image]

I've tried to set the text language option, but the drop down box isn't activated. When I check the document options, I see the default US english settings. How can I fix this?
PS: I've attached two screenshots below of my settings
[image]
This image shows the status bar I see. I've tried to set the language, but the field seems to be disabled.

[image]

Comment: What is the `Text Language` shown in the bottom of the window?  Also, what does `Tools -> Options: Language Settings - Writing Aides` show?

Comment: @JimK: I've attached relevant screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Change the language of the document: `Tools -> Language -> For all text -> English (USA)`.

[image: for all text]

This should change the `Text Language` shown in the bottom of the window.

[image: text language]

For future new documents, go to `Tools -> Options -> Language Settings -> Languages`.

[image: language settings]

Comment: For future reference. I downloaded a Google Doc as .odt and opened it up in LibreOffice. The language was set to (en) instead of English(USA). I had to select all the text and use Tools -> Language -> Selection ... to get the language changed.